# how to to run a downloaded project in angular?

Tags: angular

I've downloaded this project and I've run `npm install` to install node modules so I can run it and it gave me these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.5" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\danzer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\danzer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-03T12_10_23_911Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try to manually install latest version of jasmine-core plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this and it will work

```sh
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```